# Insert query if no duplicate of singular value

Tags: sql, database

I have a table with various planets on it and users have the option to create their own planets. However, I do not want there to be planets with the same name so I am attempting to create a query that only inserts a planet if it's name is not the duplicate of an already created planet. This is what I have so far for my query:

```
   private static final String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO tutorial.planet"
            + " (planet_name, planet_type, habitable_flg, planet_radius, distance_from_sun, days_in_year, population)"
            + " VALUES"
            + " (:name, :type, :habitable, :radius, :distance, :days, :population)"
            + " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT planet_name FROM tutorial.planet WHERE tutorial.planet.name = :name)";
```

The "WHERE NOT EXISTS" line is in question as my query works for regular insertions whenever I exclude that line.

Comment: you could just make the planet_name field unique, this way there cant be a name twice in the table

Comment: There is no `private static final String` in SQL. Are you using some kind of script language?

Comment: I'm coding my SQL statements in Java

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a unique constraint on the `planet_name` column?

A `UNIQUE` constraint will by default restrict the addition of a new record in the database. The database will generate an error (like this: `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint`) when trying to add a new record with the same `planet_name`

When this is handled by the database you will have to catch the exception thrown in your code.

This constraint can be added like this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE tutorial.planet   
ADD CONSTRAINT Unique_Planet_Name UNIQUE (planet_name);
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15